# python ProcessPoolExecutor memory problems

Tags: python, linux, memory, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

This is in Linux, Python 3.8.
I use `ProcessPoolExecutor` to speed up the processing of a list of large dataframes, but because they all get copied in each process, I run out of memory. How do I solve this problem?
My code looks like this:

```
def some_func(df):
   # do some work on a single pandas DataFrame
   return single_df # returns a single pandas DataFrame 

# dfs is a list of 100 dataframes
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
     dfs = list(executor.map(some_func, dfs) # here entire dfs gets copied 4 times?
     executor.shutdown(wait=True)
```

I want to minimize the unnecessary copying of data, i.e. minimize my memory footprint.
What's a good solution?

Comment: If you can pivot to using individual numpy arrays instead of entire dataframes, you can use `multiprocessing.shared_memory` to create a shared memory buffer which is accessible by multiple processes at once. With the number of arrays (100 df's * columns per df), you'll probably want to create some management code to keep track of them all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your memory problem relates to requiring enough storage to hold double or 200 dataframes, assuming that `some_func` does indeed implicitly return `None`. That is, your main process is storing the initial 100 dataframes and then it is copying these dataframes to a task queue. But as a dataframe is removed from the task queue, it will temporarily occupy storage in the address space of a pool process until the process is through with it and pulls off the next dataframe from the pool. This results in memory utilization decreasing as the processing pool is depleting tasks from the task queue until we are back to where we started (more or less). But the high-water mark will be around 200 dataframes assuming that these dataframes can be added to the queue much faster than your worker function, `some_func`, can process a dataframe. If, however, `some_func` in reality returns the dataframe, then the memory usage will not decrease as tasks complete.

The simplest thing to try is to not submit all 100 dataframes to your pool at a time, but rather split your list into chunks of 4 (your pool size), so that your high-water mark of memory utilization should be around 104 dataframes, again assuming that `some_func` is not returning a dataframe (and is instead, for example, just writing it out).

```py
def some_func(df):
   # do some work on a single pandas DataFrame
   pass


# dfs is a list of 100 dataframes
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    start = 0
    cnt = len(dfs)
    while start < cnt:
        # Do chunks of 4:
        list(executor.map(some_func, dfs[start:start+4]))
        start += 4
#executor.shutdown(wait=True) is done implicitly at end of the above block
```

**Update**

Since we now know that `some_func` actually does return a dataframe, I am assuming that you do not need the original list of dataframes when you are all through. If that assumption is wrong, then I see no way that you would not need storage for 200 dataframes, right?

So now we still submit out tasks in chunks of 4 *and* replace our input dataframes with the result dataframes:

```py
def some_func(df):
   # do some work on a single pandas DataFrame
   return single_df # returns a single pandas DataFrame

# dfs is a list of 100 dataframes
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    start = 0
    cnt = len(dfs)
    while start < cnt:
        # Do chunks of 4:
        dfs[start:start+4] = list(executor.map(some_func, dfs[start:start+4]))
        start += 4
    #executor.shutdown(wait=True) is done implicitly at end of the above block
```

Comment: That makes sense, apart from concern for this line:
`dfs = list(executor.map(some_func, dfs[start:start+4]))`. That's going to overwrite my input dfs list of size 100, with those 4 returned from that call, right. What is the cleanest way to avoid this problem, while at the same time making sure the big list dfs doesn't get copied into the sub-processes? It seems a bit like catch 22 situation.

Comment: My mistake. As long as `some_func` is not returning anything useful, no reason to do anything but to iterate the return value from the call to `map` by making a list out of it. Simply do not assign that value back to list

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, but ‘some_func’ returns a single data frame. I will edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly, thanks. But my concern is with this line
`dfs[start:start+4] = list(executor.map(some_func, dfs[start:start+4]))`
Are we sure that the processes will receive copy of only that slice of the `dfs` list, and not the entire list? Because I thought all variables (entire context) gets copied to each process, this is my worry.

Comment: In each iteration of the loop you are submitting 4 tasks (dataframes) and what is coming back is a list of 4 dataframes that are replacing the 4 dataframes that were submitted. Create a list of numbers 0, 1, 2  … 99 instead of dataframes and have your worker function return its argument * 2 and then print out the final dfs list when the loop is terminated. You will see 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10  … 198.

Comment: Nothing is copied to processes. The tasks are written to a queue and a process, if it is currently idle, reads from the queue the next task to process. When the process finishes processing the task it becomes idle and goes back to read from the queue again.

Comment: And what you are not showing in your code is how these 100 dataframes are created. Do they really need to be created all at once and then passed? What is done with them after the results are returned? Do you need all 100 results at the same time? There may be other creative ways of getting around the memory problem. You don't have to answer these questions -- they are just something for you to think about. But sometimes when people post too minimal a reproducible example, they deprive themselves of getting the best answer -- or even any answer.